# passing variable from aspx JScript code behind to markup aspx file

Tags: asp.net, code-behind, jscript

I can't find a way to pass a variable declared in my code-behind aspx.js file to the corresponding code-behind.aspx markup file. The error I keep getting is this:

```
Parser Error Message: Code blocks are not allowed in this file.
```

My Code-Behind.aspx.js looks like this:

```
import System;

package Test {
    class CodeBehind extends System.Web.UI.Page {
        public var my_var;

        public function Page_Load(sender, E:System.EventArgs) {
            my_var = "This is my_var.";
        }
    }
}
```

I compile the code-behind file manually like this:

> jsc.exe /t:library /out:bin\codebehind.dll codebehind.aspx.js

The Code-Behind.aspx looks like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="JScript"  Inherits="Test.CodeBehind" CompilationMode="Never" %>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Hello World Test</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY STYLE="font-size:12;font-family:arial,verdana,sans-serif;">
<FORM RUNAT="server">
    <%= my_var %>
</FORM>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I know there are ASP.NET server controls such as asp:label and all that stuff but all I want is print out the contents of simple variables which serve as placeholders.

I don't want the website to compile everytime it is requested and I would like to keep the CompilationMode option set to "Never" and compile all code manually if possible.

Thanks!

Comment: `Page.Form.InnerHtml = my_var;`

Answer (score 0):

**Codebehind**

```
protected string my_var { get; set; }

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    my_var = "Hello";
}
```

**html**

```
<%= my_var %>
```

Comment: I cannot execute code in the aspx file, I believe that is the problem. But how are you supposed to do this then?